# Contract First Approach with Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey, contract-first

I am currently working on a projects API layer with an existing REST services using JERSEY. Most of the initial services are created in a contract last approach utilizing jaxb annotations etc.. Lately, i was asked to do a contract first approach instead due to versioning concerns easier 3rd party integration by providing the schema to other clients.

can anyone provide a useful resource or a reading material for a contract first approach with REST as most of the stuff i find related to contract first approach points me to SOAP examples.

Thanks

Comment: By "contract first" do you mean "design the API first?"

Comment: yes Bill, basically what was requested is that i write the xsd first and from there generate the classes to be used via maven jaxb plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong with using XSD to define your XML responses, however, you really need to consider you URI namespace for the problem domain. RESTful Web Services (O'Reilly 2007, Richardson & Ruby) has a couple of good chapters on this (chapters 4-6). There's a lot of other good stuff in this book.

Comment: Thanks! ill have a look at the book